# Save several Pandas DataFrames into single Excel file

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I have several Pandas data frames that i would like to save into single MS Excel file, each dataframe as separate sheet in this file.
Any advice more than welcome.
Felix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sheet_name` argument of `to_excel` like below example.

> **pandas.DataFrame.to_excel**
>
> If passing an existing ExcelWriter object, then the sheet will be added to the existing workbook. This can be used to save different DataFrames to one workbook:
>
> ```
> writer = ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') 
> df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
> df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2') 
> writer.save()
> ```
>
> For compatibility with to_csv, to_excel serializes lists and dicts to strings before writing.
>
> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: the only modification I'd make is to use the writer as a context manager, means if an exception occurs it will close the file. 

    with Excelwriter('output.xlsx') as writer: 
        df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
        df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')

Comment: Works PERFECT! :-)