# How to update the same excel sheet with different dataframe without overwriting the previous data present in excel file using python2.7.14?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have 3 different dataframe which I am generating the dataframe in looping. So currently I am converting the data frame to excel file. I am able to convert only one data frame to excel. But I need to update all the 3 dataframes with different data should be appended one after the other in excel file. How can I achieve that? Is it possible to do?

My Current code. I am converting different dataframe to different sheets of the excel file.

**Note: I need to append to only one excel sheet**.

```
for itr in range(0,3):
        df["users"] = UserArray
        for action in range(len(ColumnName)):
            Array = []
            for user in range(int(usercount)): 
                #calling Copylogs function to copy the required logs and actions in script into another file        
                Array.append(CopyLogs(abs_read_path,itr+1,user+1,ColumnName[action]))
            Array1 = AverageStatistics(Array)
            df[ColumnName[action]] = Array1
        print df
        print "\n"
        df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="TimeStampsOfItr="+str(itr+1))
    writer.save()
```

Comment: What behavior are you seeing with your code that is not what you expect? Also, have you tried moving the writer.save() into the loop? That file needs to be closed before the next to_excel tries to write to it.

Comment: If we move writer.save() to the loop, code does not work. Because here I am converting the data to different sheets every time.

Comment: yes, I couldn't edit that comment after a few minutes as more information was added.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean writing the dataframes to different sheets in the file? That can be done with the sheet_name= parameter of pandas.DataFrame.to_excel although you'll have to make sure each write is complete and the file released before doing the next one. Try moving the writer.save() into the loop. If you don't want to do that [establish the writer instance separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465746/save-several-pandas-dataframes-into-single-excel-file?rq=1) and use it for multiple dataframes on different sheets.

If you want to successively write to the same sheet in the excel file but in different places that overlap in space you'll need to compose the different data together in pandas and then write to the target sheet from a single dataframe. The particulars of pandas writing to excel don't provide a mechanism for writing just odd rows then just even rows, for example.

Edit: more information added to question

Comment: No.. I know how to update different dataframe to different sheet. But I need to update in the same sheet one below another

Comment: That would be the second scenario. Writing a sheet from pandas writes the whole sheet, sounds like you should try composing the combined sheet in pandas before writing it out, sorry. Note that in your reference code you are writing to different sheets because itr is changing the sheetname

Comment: @Prajna - Did this work out for you? Don't forget to let us know and to select an answer if something here helped so that others know when they come here from searching :)